# Automatic setup of App Engine Remote API on webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, remoteapi

Configuring the remote_api for AppEngine on Python 2.7, I need to set up the configuration calls to create and configure the dabase call stubs so that I don't have to replicate the configuration call in every REST resource and handler.  The code I want to have is something similar to this:

```
def configure_remote_api():
    try:
        from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
        remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func, 'myapp.appspot.com')
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

What I want is to set it up so it is modularly called, and doesn't have to be replicated all over the application code, not even `configure_remote_api()`.  This way, we can keep our codebase clean and have automatic remote_api use whenever developing locally.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can put the call in appengine_config.py.  That usually gets loaded pretty early on.  (But please check.)